# Parallel surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

For a regular surface $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}(u,v)$

Define $\mathbf{y}(u,v) = \mathbf{x}(u,v) + t \mathbf{N} (u,v)$ where $\mathbf{N}$ is the unit normal of $\mathbf{x}$

How could I show the following?
$\mathbf{y}_u \times \mathbf{y}_v = (1-2Ht+Kt^2)\mathbf{x}_u \times \mathbf{x}_v$

where $H$ is the mean curvature of $\mathbf{x}$ and $K$ is its Gaussian curvature

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you computed $y_u$  in terms of $x_u$ and $N_u$? Do you have a formula for $H$ and $K$ in terms of derivatives of $x$ and $N$?

Comment: I have computed $y_u=x_u+tN_u$, $y_v=x_v+tN_v$, I'm not aware of such a formula

Comment: @user142702 These are Bertrand parallels. Please show your work.

Comment: Without such a formula, you're not going to be able to complete the problem. What *are* your definitions of $H$ and $K$? When you compute the cross product of $y_u$ and $y_v$, you certainly get an $x_u \times x_v$ term, but you get three others as well; can you give a reason why their sum also points in the $x_u \times x_v$ direction?

Answer (score 1):

> **Fundamental Forms**
>   $$
> \begin{pmatrix} E & F \\ F & G \end{pmatrix}= 
> \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{x}_{u} \\ \mathbf{x}_{v} \end{pmatrix}
> \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{x}_{u} & \mathbf{x}_{v} \end{pmatrix} $$
>
> $$
>  \begin{pmatrix} e & f \\ f & g \end{pmatrix}=
> -\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{N}_{u} \\ \mathbf{N}_{v} \end{pmatrix}
>  \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{x}_{u} & \mathbf{x}_{v} \end{pmatrix} $$
>
> Let $\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{N}_{u} \\ \mathbf{N}_{v} \end{pmatrix}=
> \mathbb{A} \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{x}_{u} \\ \mathbf{x}_{v} \end{pmatrix}$ 
>   where $\mathbb{A}=
> \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{pmatrix}$.
>
> Now
>   \begin{align*}
>    \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{N}_{u} \\ \mathbf{N}_{v} \end{pmatrix}
>    \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{x}_{u} & \mathbf{x}_{v} \end{pmatrix} &=
>    \mathbb{A} \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{x}_{u} \\ \mathbf{x}_{v} \end{pmatrix}
>    \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{x}_{u} & \mathbf{x}_{v} \end{pmatrix} \\
>   -\begin{pmatrix} e & f \\ f & g \end{pmatrix} &=
>    \mathbb{A} \begin{pmatrix} E & F \\ F & G \end{pmatrix} \\
>    \mathbb{A} &=
>   -\begin{pmatrix} e & f \\ f & g \end{pmatrix}
>    \begin{pmatrix} E & F \\ F & G \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
> \end{align*}
>
> The principal curvatures $k_{1}, k_{2}$ are the eigenvalues of $-\mathbb{A}$.  That is
>
> $$H=\frac{k_{1}+k_{2}}{2}=-\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{tr} \mathbb{A}$$
>   $$K=k_{1} k_{2}=(-1)^{2} \det \mathbb{A}$$

\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{y}_{u} &= \mathbf{x}_{u}+t\mathbf{N}_{u} \\
  &= \mathbf{x}_{u}+t(a_{11} \mathbf{x}_{u}+a_{12} \mathbf{x}_{v}) \\
  \mathbf{y}_{v} &= \mathbf{x}_{v}+t\mathbf{N}_{v} \\
  &= \mathbf{x}_{v}+t(a_{21} \mathbf{x}_{u}+a_{22} \mathbf{x}_{v}) \\
  \mathbf{y}_{u} \times \mathbf{y}_{v} &=
  [1+t(a_{11}+a_{22})+t^{2}(a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21})]
  \mathbf{x}_{u} \times \mathbf{x}_{v} \\
  &= (1-2Ht+Kt^{2}) \mathbf{x}_{u} \times \mathbf{x}_{v}
\end{align*}

Comment: The convention of normal cuvatrue $\kappa_{n}=\frac{II}{I}$ is used here.  See also http://www.cad.zju.edu.cn/home/zhx/GM/002/00-sg.pdf.